# Let I and J be ideals of a ring R. How to prove that IJ is closed under multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let I and J be ideals of a ring R (not necessarily unitary). I need to prove that IJ is an ideal of R contained in $I\cap J$. I can prove all the other properties of ideal. However, I cannot prove that IJ is closed under multiplication. I think I need this because I have to show that IJ is a subring of R and IJ is a subring of R if and only if IJ is closed under multiplication.

Comment: You need more than that, don't you? You need that it's stable under multiplication by any element of $R$, not just the ones in $IJ$.

Comment: I know but that is the only thing that I can't prove. The rest I know how to prove.

Comment: @user2675516 Hoot's point is this: One of the things you need to show is that $R \cdot IJ \subset IJ$.  If you're saying that you know how to prove this, then what you want follows immediately: $IJ \cdot IJ \subset R \cdot IJ \subset IJ$.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some confusion here.  To show $IJ$ is an ideal you need to show:
(1) $IJ$ is a subgroup; and (2) If $r \in R$ and $\alpha \in IJ$ then $r\alpha$ and $\alpha r$ are both in $IJ$.  As mentioned in the comments this is stronger then just being closed under multiplication (where you only consider $r$ from the subset $IJ$).

So let $r \in R$ and let $\alpha = i_1 j_1 + \ldots + i_1 j_1 \in IJ$.  Then 
$$ r \alpha = (r i_1) j_1 + \ldots + (r i_n) j_n \in IJ$$ 
since each $r i_k$ is in $I$, since $I$ is an ideal (again using that same property of ideals).

You should argue similarly that $\alpha r \in IJ$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i,\sum_{i=1}^nc_id_i\in IJ$

then $(a_1b_1+a_2b_2+...+a_nb_n)(c_1d_1+c_2d_2+...c_nd_n)=(a_1b_1c_1)d_1+(a_1b_1c_2)d_2+...+(a_ib_ic_j)d_j+..\in IJ$

use the distributive property and the fact that both $I$ and $J$ are ideals

Comment: where do you need commutativity here  @PedroTamaroff

Comment: why is abc in I?

Comment: Dont you mean associative property rather than distributive?

Comment: $a\in I;b\in J $ and hence in $R$ so $ab\in I;c\in I $ and hence

Comment: associative and distributive both @Sodan